# $\int_ {0}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{3x}-e^x)dx}{x(e^x+1)(e^{3x}+1)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

$$\int_ {0}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{3x}-e^x) \ \mathrm dx}{x(e^x+1)(e^{3x}+1)}$$

I tried converting it to $$\int_ {0}^{\infty} \frac{\big((e^{3x}+1)-(e^x+1)\big) \ \mathrm dx}{x(e^x+1)(e^{3x}+1)}$$

integral-calculator.com says no antiderivative found.

I would like to see how it is solved by Feynman's Trick.

Comment: WolframAlpha [evaluates such](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+from+0+to+inf+of+%28e%5E%283x%29-e%5Ex%29%2F%28x%28e%5Ex%2B1%29%28e%5E%283x%29%2B1%29%29) to be $\approx0.549306$

Comment: @Akalanka OP already did that. That was also the only thing OP did, why are you repeating it?

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3440498/int-0-infty-frace3x-exxe3x1ex1-dx) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3461721/evaluate-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-mathrme3x-mathrmexx/3461753#3461753). Although, Ninad's answer is amazing and I would prefer to keep it.

Comment: @Axion004 as user Ninad Munsi suggested it may be solved by Feynman's trick ,so I want to see it as I don't have  knowledge of multivariable calculus.

Comment: As I probably should have mentioned, the Feynman trick solution is *much* harder. Just learn the basics of multiple integration (constant bounds), it will take you an hour. Also you can't say you don't know multivariable calculus, Feynman's trick *is* multivariable calculus, so you do know a little :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will present a simple solution using Feynman's method, as you asked for.  Consider the following parameterized integral:
$$I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax}-e^x}{x\left(e^{ax}+1\right) \left(e^x+1\right)} \; dx$$
Now, differentiate both sides with respect to $a$ (factor out the terms independent of $a$ for simplicity):
$$I'(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x \left(e^x+1\right)} \cdot \frac{x e^{ax}\left(e^{ax}+1\right)-xe^{ax}\left(e^{ax}-e^x\right)}{{\left(e^{ax}+1\right)}^2} \; dx$$
Simplifying this yields an elegant integral:
$$I'(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax}}{{\left(e^{ax}+1\right)}^2} \; dx$$
$$I'(a)=-\frac{1}{a\left(e^{ax}+1\right)} \bigg \rvert_{0}^{\infty}$$
$$I'(a)=\frac{1}{2a}$$
Integrate both sides with respect to $a$:
$$I(a)=\frac{\ln{a}}{2}+C$$
If you plug in $a=1$ into the original, you get that $I(1)=0$.
$$0=\frac{\ln{1}}{2}+C \implies C=0$$

Therefore, your integral is: $$\boxed{I=I(3)=\frac{\ln{3}}{2}}$$

Comment: Why does $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax}}{{\left(e^{ax}+1\right)}^2} \; dx \implies\frac{1}{a\left(e^{ax}+1\right)} \bigg \rvert_{0}^{\infty}?$$

When I did the substitution $u=e^{ax}+1$, I found that the lower limit was $2$ instead of $0$ but I think that I screwed up. Is this step missing a negative sign:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax}}{{\left(e^{ax}+1\right)}^2} \; dx \implies-\frac{1}{a\left(e^{ax}+1\right)} \bigg \rvert_{0}^{\infty}?$$

Comment: @Axion004 It is missing a negative sign but my work following it is using the correct result, I'll fix that.  If $u=e^{ax}+1$ then $du=a e^{ax} dx$.  Rewrite the integral as $$\int_2^{\infty} \frac{1}{a} \cdot \frac{du}{u^2} = -\frac{1}{au} \bigg \rvert_2^{\infty}$$ Here you still get $\frac{1}{2a}$ with the lower bound of $2$ and upper bound of $\infty$ after the substitution.  In my answer I sort of did the substitution in my head and substituted $e^{ax}+1$ back for $u$ so that's why the lower bound is $0$ in my answer.  it's the same thing.

Comment: @Axion004 I edited my previous comment explaining it.  If something's unclear let me know.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks for answering these comments (+1).

Answer (score 17):

You were on the right track. The integral separates out into

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x}\left(\frac{1}{e^x+1}-\frac{1}{e^{3x}+1}\right) = \int_0^
\infty\int_1^3 \frac{e^{xy}}{(e^{xy}+1)^2}\:dy\:dx$$

Then we can swap the order of integration to get

$$\int_1^3 \frac{dy}{y}\frac{-1}{e^{xy}+1}\Biggr|_0^\infty = \int_1^3\frac{dy}{2y} = \frac{\log 3}{2}$$

Comment: I don't understand what you did,I am in highschool.

Comment: @user69608 it is not a highschool-level integral

Comment: It came in a test for JEE.

Comment: @user69608 you have to know some multivariable calculus for JEE, especially if you want a high math and physics score. This is not particularly complicated multivariable, either, because the bounds are all constants, nor is a multivariable change of variable necessary.

Comment: ok thanks, though i suspect if there is a simpler method

Comment: @user69608 I can guarantee you there is not, as I have taught multivariable calculus for a long time. This is a special case of a class intergrals known as [Frullani Integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral). You can see that the proof immediately relies on multivariable calculus (particularly Fubini's theorem). In fact you even found that no elementary antiderivative exists, which is what almost all high school calculus relies on.

Comment: @user69608 your other choice would be Feynman's trick, which is, again, a multivariable calculus method.

Comment: i understand feynman's trick, how would we be doing from that?

Comment: Very neat trick. Thanks for sharing the link!

Comment: @NinadMunshi Just a curiosity. My upvoted there is...but why do you use double integrals with these limits? At the this moment I not remember.

Comment: @Sebastiano you might want to check out Frullani integral on Wikipedia

Comment: @sai-kartik Thank you very much...I have not read well. I have seen now.

Answer (score 10):

We can write $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(3x)}{x} dx, ~~~\phi(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^x}$$
Next we use the ideas of Frullani's Integration formula:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral

Since $\int^{\infty}_0 \phi(x) dx$ is convergent at $\infty$, then
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\phi(ax)-\phi(bx)}{x} dx=\phi_0 \ln \frac{b}{a},~~ \phi_0=\lim_{x\to 0} \phi(x)=\frac{1}{2}.$$
So $$I=\frac{\ln 3}{2}$$